# Make laravel API with filament admin panel, Arduino esp32 and React js SPA app work with each other

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, esp32

I am trying to make laravel API with filament admin panel, Arduino esp32 and React js SPA app work with each other, but when i access `http://192.168.0.105:8000/admin/login` or my frontend `http://localhost:3000/login`  and trying to log in I face 419 expired and csrf token mismatch.
I do `php artisan serve --host 192.168.0.105 --port=8000`  for laravel app
For react js i start app on localhost:3000
and arduino has a static ip `http://192.168.0.30`

Also I am using Breeze for authentication.

I tried various configurations of SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS, but every attempt failed.

I guess the issue is in my env configuration.

```
APP_URL=http://192.168.0.105:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

config/sanctum

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

config/cors

```
    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],
```

If I change my APP_URL to localhost:8000 and start like php artisan serve, my laravel api and react app communicate fine, but then arduino fails to send requests to my 192.168.0.105:8000

How can I resolve the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix it.
My env config now looks like

```
APP_URL=https://192.168.0.105:8000
FRONTEND_URL=https://192.168.0.105:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=192.168.0.105:8000,192.168.0.105,192.168.0.105:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=.192.168.0.105
```

I added a dot in session domain

Answer (score 0):

I get a similair problem 2 days ago , when i post from an API test like Thunder Client i get 419 and 419 means the problem is in CSRF Nothing else , and I made this :

```
Route::post('store', [GreenhouseDataController::class, 'store'])->middleware('apiKeySecret')->withoutMiddleware([\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class]);
```

I disable VerifyCsrfToken for the post and create my own middleware called apikeysecret